Management of different web domains associated to different servers running on the same machine
I have a local machine using Debian 12 in the company lab. 
On this local machine I have different servers running and reachable from different web addresses. 
Let's say the first one is reachable from the web at: https://firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org 
And the second reachable at: https://seconddomain.dnsprovider2.org 
The two servers are running on Docker containers, listening to different ports:
0.0.0.0:21300->21300/tcp, :::21300->21300/tcp
8971/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9969->8969/tcp, :::9969->8969/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9972->8972/tcp, :::9972->8972/tcp
0.0.0.0:5332->5332/tcp, :::5332->5332/tcp

For these websites I set apache2  listening on the ports 80 and 443 to redirect to the respective ports, e.g. 21300 and 9969, that is in the conf file of Apache, as for instance: 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org
ServerAlias *.firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org
Redirect permanent / https://firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org
ServerAlias *.firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org/privkey.pem

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9969/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9969/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dmpr_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dmpr_access.log combined
</VirtualHost> 

I used Let'sEncrypt to get SSL certificates and everything correctly works. All the servers are reachable remotely from the web. I set on the router the port forwarding for the ports 80 and 443. 
To reach the servers from computers in the same LAN, I've just set the host file in /etc/hosts adding:
192.XXX.X.XXX   firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org where 192.XXX.X.XXX is the local IP of the machine in the LAN. 
In the dnsprovider1.org I set the web IP of the router associated to the domain name. This system is good for having few web servers. 
Now I'm in the situation to have our own domain name, associated to the company website, let's say: www.mycompany.com 
I've created some pages that redirect to the IP of the router where is the local machine hosting all the servers, like www.mycompany.com/server1, www.mycompany.com/server2, etc...
I need a system to manage the previous existing servers domains and the new ones that I want to add. Let's say I need to have 10 or 20 servers running on the same machine and it's important to find a way to easily manage all the certificates.  I want to use the existing and working certificate for the website hosted on a web hosting server.
The first question is about the following. What is the best way to manage many domain names associated to many servers running in the same machines listening to different ports? I thought Caddy2 is the solution but I want your suggestion if this can work also with Apache, and if so, how?
The second question is about the following. How to use the SSL certificate of the domain www.mycompany.com that is well working for all the servers? Is it possible to do that? Following the same procedures of the previous dns providers, that is  $ sudo certbot --apache -d www.mycompany.com it returns an error as not authorized
$ sudo certbot --apache -d www.mycompany.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for www.mycompany.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate  Authority reported these problems:
Domain: www.mycompany.com
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 39.56.289.27: Invalid response from https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/cEr8rw-2YMjxJW5NM1pS_HP-S4p32npL2hw-sIywXnM: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

I don't have access to the certificate of the domain www.mycompany.com even if I can manage the Wordpress web site hosted there. What could be the solution?

I'm not sure why you need that certificate on all of those servers in the first place? Your clients don't talk to them directly, they only talk to the reverse proxy, it seems?

I got your point and it should be something like www.domain.come/address1 , www.domain.come/address2 , etc... And this could be helpful if it is www.mycompany/addressN But I need to know how to do this?

Why would the verification of www.mycompany.com fail? Will the test clients LE uses find out the correct IP for the hostname www.mycompany.com via DNS? Will requests to that IP ultimately reach your apache? Does your apache have a corresponding vhost? Does your apache log also show an error for that .well-known file?

I just noted that the failed challenge is https:, not http:. Is this because you are using TLS-ALPN-01 or does your www.mydomain.com already employ http to https redirection?

@HagenvonEitzen www.mydomain.com has its own certificate SSL DV and it is provided by the host of the website: the host provides the server and the domain name for the website. Through WordPress managing this website, I created a redirection to the static IP of the router of the company on a specific page. It works, so www.domain.come/address1 goes effectively to https://routerIP, and if I have active only one server on the local machine, apache2 redirects correctly to https://firstdomain.dnsprovider1.org My doubt is on how to manage many different servers with different origin addresses

The required solution should: 1# forward connection requests from different sites (www.mycompany.com/address1, www.mycompany.com/address2, etc..) to their respective servers 2# ensure that the SSL certificate for HTTPS to be presented to the client, is that of the site's domain (www.mycompany.com)
